# How to safely use c-string in C embedded applications

Tags: c, embedded, c-strings

After realizing that String type (with capital S) on Arduino was a big source of troubles (cf. https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/), I am trying to deal with c-string to be more safe and robust for embedded applications.

However, I am facing some issues regarding the safety. To illustrate my problem, let's take a function of md5 hashing that will receive a string message, concatenate a private key and then compute and return the hash as a string.

I came to this function:

```
#define MD5_PRIVATE_KEY   "my_private_key"

void ComputeMd5(const char* msg, char* hashBuffer, uint8_t hashBufferSize)
{
    if( (hashBuffer == NULL) || (hashBufferSize == 0) )
    {
        /* INVALID ARG */
        *hashBuffer = '\0';
        return;
    }

    if(hashBufferSize <= HASH_SIZE)
    {
        /* SIZE ERROR */
        *hashBuffer = '\0';
        return;
    }

    uint16_t toHashSize = strlen(msg) + strlen(MD5_PRIVATE_KEY) + 1;
    char toHash[toHashSize] = "";

    strcat(toHash, MD5_PRIVATE_KEY);
    strcat(toHash, msg);

    strncpy(hashBuffer, MD5(toHash, HASH_SIZE), hashBufferSize);
}
```

With this function, calls to `strlen(msg)` and `strcat(toHash, msg)` are not safe since we don't know the length of `msg` to use `strnlen()` and `strncat()` instead, and we don't even know if `msg` is a valid null-terminated string.

My question is, would it be a good practice to add the msg length in the prototype such as `void ComputeMd5(const char* msg, uint16_t msgSize, char* hashBuffer, uint8_t hashBufferSize)` in order to use the 'n' version of `strlen`and `strcat`? And, is it acceptable to rely on the caller to provide a valid null-terminated string or is it the responsibility of this function to make check (if yes, how?).

Maybe there is a complete different design to do it and I don't know it (but I still want to avoid dynamic allocation since it's considered as not safe for embedded applications).

Sorry if this isn't very clear, it is still confuse in my head. I'm looking for a discussion about best practices to use c-string in the safer way.

Thanks.

Comment: Ehm... `if( (hashBuffer == NULL)  ... *hashBuffer = '\0';`  doesn't look very useful.

Comment: The caller must ensure the parameters it is passing are valid strings, and this is true for any, not just embedded system. Where are these coming from in the first place?

Comment: If you do not trust the caller of that function to provide a valid nul-terminated string, why do you trust them to provide the correct length as parameter?

Comment: Yep , true. But if only `hashBufferSize == 0` condition is true, it might be interesting to have `hashBuffer` to null no?

Comment: `char toHash[toHashSize] = "";` That is not legal in C. Variable length arrays cannot be initilized.

Comment: You have this check in your second `if` condition. In your first `if` you will happily dereference a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Variable length array did compile, missing compiler flags? 

@EugeneSh. let say this function is called by the code responsible of communication (e.g. `socketWrite()`, or `uartWrite()`). 
But your point is right, actually I have to trust the caller about the validity of the parameters. However is it a way to check if the parameter is a valid null-terminated string?

Comment: _"a big source of troubles"_ - such as? The article seems to base some of the claims that `String`s are bad on bad coding style, such as passing `String`s _by-value_ instead of by `const&` etc. You can also enable C++17 and get RVO to avoid the problem with temporaries in the situations it mentions. Even most C++14 compilers will do copy elision in many cases.

Comment: The code responsible for communication should know what the maximum buffer length is. You *can* use this information in conjunction with `strnlen` function to make sure the string passed is legal.

Comment: @Gerhardh Arduino is C++

Comment: @0___________ Ah, I forgot. But then it also must be an extension, or did C++ introduce VLA lately?

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, it's an extension. `g++` has VLA:s and afaik the arduino compiler is based on (or _is_) `g++`.

Comment: @Gerhardh And also Arduino is gcc as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Arduino is not C only C++;

1. There is no 100% **safe** way of dealing with pointers and arrays (including null character terminated char arrays called C strings).

Your attempt to make them "safe" is extremely unsafe.

1.

```
    if( (hashBuffer == NULL) || (hashBufferSize == 0) )
    {
        /* INVALID ARG */
        *hashBuffer = '\0';
        return;
    }
```

If `hashBuffer == NULL` it is undefined behaviour.

2. You do not check if `msg` is not `NULL`
3. You do not check if `toHashSize` is a reasonable sized.
4. `strncpy` is not a safe function. If `MD5` function returns a string longer or the same size as `hashBufferSize` the string will not be null character terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem even if the parameters are perfectly valid. For example:

```
    uint16_t toHashSize = strlen(msg) + strlen(MD5_PRIVATE_KEY) + 1;
    char toHash[toHashSize] = "";
```

VLAs may be (and to the best of my knowledge usually are) allocated on stack. How much stack you have, and whether it will fit in it in the case of a particular `msg` you don't know and don't check (ignoring the initialization issue for a second). So in your attempts to avoid a vulnaribility you just created a new one.

So yes, if you add length to the parameters you could validate that the `msg` is in fact a null-terminated string of that length, but that's assuming you can trust the caller to provide the correct length. But if you trust the caller to provide a correct length - you should be able to trust them to provide a null-terminated string to begin with, shouldn't you?

Or, just don't treat it as a string but rather as a random binary buffer that you're hashing, in which case `length` parameter is required and `\0` terminator is not. I don't know which MD5 implementation you're using, but you can hash a random binary buffer, it doesn't have to be a string (your `MD5` call seems to be expecting a string).

Answer (score 0):

- The way to deal with error handling in C (or in any sane program) is to place the error handling as close to the error source as possible. If you suspect that strings are too large or not null terminated for whatever reason, then you need to write code ensuring that they are valid at the point where you receive the strings. Not in some completely unrelated hash function!
- Similarly, if you suspect that some pointer is set to NULL for reasons unknown, you need to deal with that at the point where it might occur, not inside some completely unrelated function.

  It is also bad practice to place checks like `if( (hashBuffer == NULL) || (hashBufferSize == 0) )` inside functions, because it slows down the normal use-case where the caller is passing on perfectly valid data.
- In case you do implement a function with extensive error handling, you should let it return a proper error code with an enum. Not by silently setting data to something like `*hashBuffer = '\0';` and then merrily move on with the execution - that's not error *handling*, that's error *hiding*.
- `char toHash[toHashSize] = "";` Using VLA is usually not a great idea in embedded systems that might be tight on stack space. If you are sure that this function isn't called often and that your stack has margins, then sure you can do things like this. But it would make far more sense to do `static char toHash[MAX_SIZE]="";` since your function always needs to be able with the worst case scenario.

  Although in this specific case, what makes the most sense is to do caller allocation. There's no obvious reason why you need to create a local temporary buffer, it just chews up memory and performance. Just access `hashBuffer` directly without any middle man.
- `strncpy` is a dangerous function that should never be used in C programs, because it wasn't designed to be used with C strings. Detailed explanation here: [Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/281518)